# JSON Youtube deserialization : How to keep \n of Description field

Tags: c#, json, youtube, deserialization

I´m doing this :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
string s = wc.DownloadString("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + Request.QueryString["idVideo"] + "?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true");

 JObject JObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
 var entry = JObj["entry"];

 string Description = entry["media$group"]["media$description"]["$t"].ToString();
```

The "s" string has de "\n" chars. But "Description" has only the text.

How should I do to keep the newline in the Description ?

TIA.

Comment: Are you sure?  When I try it I get newlines in the description (I used 9bZkp7q19f0 for the id):  YG-eShop: http://www.ygeshop.com\n \n===============================\nPSY CONCERT \"HAPPENING\"\n2013.4.13. SAT 6:30PM\nTHE SEOUL WORLD CUP STADIUM\n

Comment: It´s true, Steve. In fact, it seems that the \n are removed at this time : `code` description.Text = Description; `code` <br/>Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I can't suggest anything because the "\n" are not removed on my machine.   Maybe they never existed in your text or maybe you are looking at them with an html viewer which ignores them.  Here is how it looks on my box:  http://i.imgur.com/y2nFVfH.png

Comment: Yes, in my viewer the text appears correctly too. The problem happens when I assign the value to a "Label.Text" control. I realized at that moment the \n is removed or ignored.Can I use another type of control to show the Description content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are showing the text in an HTML control, the "\n"'s will be ignored.

You can search and replace them with `<br />.`

Or you could put the text in a **pre** element like this.

```
 <pre id="test"></pre>

 $("#test").text("abc\nabc");
```